# Access nested JSON object value using java

Tags: java, json

```
{
    "files": {
        "f1.png": {
            "intext": "A",
            "inval": 0,
            "inbinary": false
        },
        "f2.png": {
            "intext": "A",
            "inval": 0,
            "inbinary": true
        }
    }
}
```

How to access value of inval when the f1.png value is not fixed. i.e. the name of file can be anything, its not known so how can I access value for inval field for various files in this JSON using Java?

Comment: you sure you mean Java ?

Comment: There are JSON libraries to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try below code,

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonString = "{\"files\": {\"f1.png\": {\"intext\": \"A\",\"inval\": 0,\"inbinary\": false}, \"f2.png\": {\"intext\": \"A\",\"inval\": 0,\"inbinary\": true}}}";
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject =new JSONObject(jsonString);
            JSONObject jsonChildObject = (JSONObject)jsonObject.get("files");
            Iterator iterator  = jsonChildObject.keys();
            String key = null;
            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                key = (String)iterator.next();
                System.out.println("inval value: "+((JSONObject)jsonChildObject.get(key)).get("inval"));
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Hope it solves your issue

Answer (score 1):

Using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) and `JsonNode`, you'd do:

```
private static final ObjectReader READER = new ObjectMapper()
    .getReader;

// blah

// read the node
final JsonNode node = READER.readTree(fromWhatever);

// access the inner "files" member
final JsonNode filesNode = node.get("files");
```

to access the inner object.

Then to walk the `filesNode` object you'd do:

```
final Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> iterator = filesNode.fields();
Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry;
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    entry = iterator.next();
    // the "inval" field is entry.getValue().get("inval")
}
```

If you can use [this project](https://github.com/fge/jackson-coreutils) this becomes more simple:

```
// or .fromFile(), .fromReader(), others
final JsonNode node = JsonLoader.fromString(whatever);

final Map<String, JsonNode> map = JacksonUtils.nodeToMap(node.get("files"));
// walk the map
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JsonPath library to access child elements.
https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

It can be as simple as

```
List<String> names = JsonPath.read(json, "$.files.*);
```

With some modifications.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ObjectMapper.

First create a class Image.

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Image {

    private String intext;
    private Integer inval;
    private Boolean inbinary;

}
```

and convert to Map

```
final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
final String jsonString =
      "{\"files\": {\"f1.png\": {\"intext\": \"A\",\"inval\": 0,\"inbinary\": false}, \"f2.png\": {\"intext\": \"A\",\"inval\": 0,\"inbinary\": true}}}";
  final Map<String, Map<String, Image>> output =
      objectMapper.readValue(
          jsonString, new TypeReference<Map<String, Map<String, Image>>>() {});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for nested array type,

```
{
"combo":    [
                {"field":"divisions"},
                {"field":"lob"}
]
```

}
 below code will help.

```
Iterator<?> keys = jsnObj.keys();

    while(keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = (String) keys.next();
        JSONArray list = (JSONArray) jsnObj.get(key);
        if(list==null || list.length()==0)
            return null;
        List<String> comboList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0;i<list.length();i++){
            JSONObject jsonObject =  (JSONObject)list.get(i);
            if(jsonObject==null)
                continue;
            comboList.add((String)jsonObject.get("fields"));
        }
    }
```