# How to parse this json file with an inner layer?

Tags: java, json

JSON:

```
{  
   "prop":"property",
   "inputInfo":{  
      "sku":"6157068",
      "inputText":"iphone"
   }
}
```

Code:

```
JSONObject inputObject = JSON.parseObject(input);
String prop = (String)inputObject.get("property");
```

But how to get the inner layer of 'sku' & 'inputText'?

I am using Alibaba json library in Java.

Comment: You should tag the question with the language you are using. Looks like Java to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access nested JSON object value using java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17062945/218196).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used the Alibaba library but doesn't it have a `getJSONObject()` method that you can use on `inputObject`? I have done this before but I used `org.json` library.

**JSON:**

```
    {"circle":{
        "radius":255819.07998349078,
        "center":{
            "lat":00.000000000000000,
            "lng":00.000000000000000
            }
         }
    }
```

**Java**

```
    JSONObject shape = new JSONObject(entity.getJsonLocation());

    double latitude = shape.getJSONObject("circle")
                           .getJSONObject("center")
                           .getDouble("lat");

    double longitude = shape.getJSONObject("circle")
                            .getJSONObject("center")
                            .getDouble("lng");
```

This example for instance gets the JSON and creates a `JSONObject shape`. I can then get the inner json objects by calling `getJSONObject()` on `shape`.

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a bean at first, for instance,

```
public class DemoInfo {

private String id;
private String city;

public void setId(String id) {
     this.id = id;
 }
 public String getId() {
     return id;
 }

public void setCity(String city) {
     this.city = city;
 }
 public String getCity() {
     return city;
 }

}
```

then,

```
String s = "{\"id\":\"0375\",\"city\":\"New York\"}";  

DemoInfo info = JSON.parseObject(s, DemoInfo.class);
```

or you can use map instead.

```
JSON.parseObject(s, HashMap.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this,

```
JSONObject inputInfoObject = inputObject.getJSONObject("inputInfo");
String sku = inputInfoObject.getString("sku");
String inputText = inputInfoObject.getString("inputText");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use GSON the following is possible

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String json = "{\"prop\":\"property\",\"inputInfo\":{\"sku\":\"6157068\",\"inputText\":\"iphone\"}}";

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    HashMap<String, Object> res = gson.fromJson(json, HashMap.class);

    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : res.entrySet()) {

        if ("inputInfo".equalsIgnoreCase(entry.getKey())) {
            HashMap<String, Object> map = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(entry.getValue()), HashMap.class);

            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> child : map.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(child.getKey() + " : " + child.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the result is

```
inputText : iphone
sku : 6157068.0
```